# CSTA Link to Hipath 3000 (CSTA II or III) on perl

Tags: perl, hyperlink, tapi, telecommunication

I need some infos about how i connect to a Hipath 3000 Series on the CSTA Interface.
I need a quickstart for the connect ... maybe someone with experience on Perl and howto make CSTA Link ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: hi, as a follow up... please we have a similar need, can you give us directions on how you achieved your solution. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a perl module which can do that a while ago, see [http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::CSTAv3::Client](http://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aCSTAv3%3a%3aClient)

Note that this implementation is quite a hack under the hood, but it should be enough to get you started.